# Make a pyramid app ready for standalone and embedded mode

Tags: plugins, pyramid

I'm developing a wiki engine. Since this application can be usefull (at least for my company's private use) in its own it should be able to run as a standalone pyramid application, with its own graphical theme. 
However a wiki feature could also be useful as part of a bigger project, and I would like to be able to include it into other pyramid applications.

I already found some pyramid features that could help me to achieve this but first I'm not sure whether it's the best way to do it and second some problems remain open.

Here are the potential issues I currently see:

- templates: how to switch between the standalone mode and the hosted mode
- host variables: event if we can reuse the host template, some variables may be needed to correctly render the templates but are not set by the guest (the wiki engine) application.
- authentication: the guest app defines its own login system (based on pyramid_persona). Can the guest application reuse the host authentication system?

My current idea is to use the `config.include()` system of pyramid. In the wiki engine, in `__init__.py` I then define an `include(config)` method in addition the the `main()` method used for the standalone mode.

In the host application  I then define a variable in the .ini file which points to the template file that the guest should use (ie `base_template = hostapp:templates/wikibase.mako`)

Inside the guest application, the `includeme()` method reads the `base_template` variable and overrides some global config.

Then each guest view work like this:

```
from pyramid.renderers import render

@view_config(route_name="display_wiki_page",  renderer=Globals.base_template)
def view_wiki(request):
    """returns a formatted page content"""
    page = request.matchdict['page']
    content = get_raw_page_content_from_database(page)

    page_formatted = render("wikiengine:templates/page_formatting_template.mako", 
        {'request': request, 'content': content} )

    return {'page_formatted': page_formatted}
```

So from this point the base template can either be the one from the guest or the host application. Both will contain something like (in mako): `${page_formatted | n }`

But this does not solve the problem of necessary host variables for the template to be rendered by the guest code. For example the host may need to have a `hot_news` variable that need to be displayed on each of the host pages, even the pages that host the wiki.

For this I plan use the event system, and add a subscriber for NewRequest or BeforeRender and set the needed variables here inside the request object.

Is this a correct approach ? Are there examples of what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pyramid's configuration mechanisms make it very easy for clients of a module to override configuration. This is one of the most powerful parts of Pyramid compared to other popular web frameworks.

`config.include()` is a good approach to solving the problem. It allows the caller to override anything defined within the include.

Assets can be overridden using `config.override_assets()`.

Sharing user information requires your module to either provide the user information or define a contract to which someone can conform allowing them to override your model.

Anyway this is obviously a huge topic. Highly modular apps written on top of pyramid include substanced, kotti, ptah, bookie, etc.

Comment: Thank you. What about passing variables from the host to the guest application. Can I append attributes the the request object with a subscriber or are there better ways ?

Comment: `config.add_request_method()`